# Minimization randomisation in trial, what to do if dropout or missing data?

Tags: clinical-trials, random-allocation

I have been asked a question on minimization randomisation in a randomised control trial. If the randomisation has allocated thirty participants to sham or treatment, but then subsequently it is discovered that two of the thirty participants only had baseline assessment and did not receive sham or 'treatment'.

How do we ensure that subsequent allocation to treatment or sham is balanced?

Do we remove the individuals and work out if the program can rebalance? (I think this is not possible looking at the documentation).

Alternatively, do we keep them as missing data and allow for this in the analysis?

Comment: Dropout is usually a planned exigency in randomized trials. If not, balance should not be an important issue unless the overall sample size and minimally important effect size are very small.